# Invalid property value with HTML / SASS element

Tags: css, sass

My element height has a **invalid property value**, I don't know Why.
Here is my SASS code:

```
.iconDiv {
    $iconDivSize: 200px;
    .icon {
        $iconDeltaHeight: calc(#{$iconDivSize} / 60.8);
        $iconHeight: calc(#{$iconDeltaHeight} * #{$iconDivSize});
        height: $iconHeight;
    }
}
```

My output element height is: `calc(calc(200px / 60.8) * 200px)`, but is invalid... Why?

Comment: Basically you cant nest `calc` like that. You need to use css variables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues, you can't nest calc and you can only have one unit declaration.

You need something like

```
$iconDivSize: 200;
.iconDiv {    
    .icon {        
        height: calc(#{$iconDivSize}px / 60.8 * #{$iconDivSize});
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/nobloss/pen/QWWrXMm)